# Tengo problemas al cargar imagenes a un recyclerview con glide desde un fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, recyclerview, glide

estoy intentando cargar imagenes con glide en un un fragment creado con recyclerview pero al ejecutarlo me vota un meensaje que dice "La app se detuvo" lo prove con el mainactivity y si me funciona pero al hacerlo con un fragment me vota error este es mi codigo:

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.tv_name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
    holder.tv_rating.setText(mData.get(position).getRating());
    holder.tv_studio.setText(mData.get(position).getStudio());
    holder.tv_category.setText(mData.get(position).getCategorie());

    //Imagenglide

    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(mData.get(position).getImg_url())
            .apply(options)
            .into(holder.img_thumbnail);

}`
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  y agrega a la pregunta la traza del error que aparece en el Logcat.

Comment: Tienes que revisar el LogCat como comenta A. Cedano, de lo contrario las causas pueden ser muchas, te sugiero tambien imprimas el valor de : mData.get(position).getImg_url() .